# Merging nested lists with overlap

Tags: python, list, merge, nested, difflib

I have to merge nested lists which have an overlap. I keep thinking that there has to be an intelligent solution using list comprehensions and probably difflib, but I can't figure out how it should work.
My lists look like this:

```
[['C', 'x', 'F'], ['A', 'D', 'E']]
```

and

```
[['x', 'F', 'G', 'x'], ['D', 'E', 'H', 'J']].
```

They are above another, like rows in a matrix. Therefore, they have overlap (in the form of

```
[['x', 'F'], ['D', 'E']]).
```

A merge should yield:

```
[['C', 'x', 'F', 'G', 'x'], ['A', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'J']].
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: As I said, list comprehensions, difflib, merging manually came to mind. I'm quite sure there's an elegant solution, I can only think of a non-elegant one (merging manually). My question is: Can someone else think of an elegant one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
list1 = [['C', 'x', 'F'], ['A', 'D', 'E']]
list2 = [['x', 'F', 'G', 'x'], ['D', 'E', 'H', 'J']]

for x in range(len(list1)):
    for element in list2[x]:
        if element not in list1[x]:
            list1[x].append(element)
    print list1[x]
```

Output:

```
['C', 'x', 'F', 'G']
['A', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'J']
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello, thank you! :) Unfortunately this will also merge lists that are not supposed to be merged, e.g.
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']] and [['X', 'Y'], ['Z', 'U']] will yield [['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y'],
['C', 'D', 'Z', 'U']]. But the first two lists had no overlap, so they shouldn't be merged.